# Fluentd doesn't connect to AWS OpenSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, fluentd, opensearch

I'm running EKS and OpenSearch in AWS, and I'm trying to run `fluentd` DaemonSet to send logs to OpenSearch. For some reason, fluentd cannot connect to OpenSearch.

The EKS cluster and OpenSearch domain run in the same VPC. The Opensearch domain has a completely permissive IAM policy and no fine-grained access control. In summary, there is password-less connection to the OpenSearch domain from the cluster.

The fluentd configuration is as such: (removing some unnecessary stuff..)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-logging
    version: v1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: fluentd-logging
      version: v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: fluentd-logging
        version: v1
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: fluentd-es
      ...
      containers:
      - name: fluentd
        image: fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1-debian-opensearch
        env:
          - name: K8S_NODE_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: spec.nodeName
          - name: FLUENT_OPENSEARCH_HOST
            #value: opensearch.storage.svc.cluster.local
            value: vpc-eks-opensearch-domain-abc.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com
          - name: FLUENT_OPENSEARCH_PORT
            value: "443"
          - name: FLUENT_OPENSEARCH_INDEX_NAME
            value: fluentd
          - name: FLUENT_OPENSEARCH_SSL_VERIFY
            value: "false"
          - name: FLUENT_OPENSEARCH_SCHEME
            value: "https"
          - name: FLUENT_OPENSEARCH_LOGSTASH_FORMAT
            value: "true"
          - name: FLUENT_CONTAINER_TAIL_PARSER_TYPE
            value: "cri"
          - name: FLUENT_CONTAINER_TAIL_PARSER_TIME_FORMAT
            value: "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%N%:z"
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
        - name: dockercontainerlogdirectory
          mountPath: /var/log/pods
          readOnly: true
        - name: config
          mountPath: /fluentd/etc/conf.d
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
      # When actual pod logs in /var/lib/docker/containers, the following lines should be used.
      # - name: dockercontainerlogdirectory
      #   hostPath:
      #     path: /var/lib/docker/containers
      # When actual pod logs in /var/log/pods, the following lines should be used.
      - name: dockercontainerlogdirectory
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log/pods
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: fluentd
```

So the fluentd configuration points to the OpenSearch domain, port 443, https scheme, and `ssl_verify` set to false.

For some reason, the log of fluentd gives me:

```
2023-04-23 17:01:49 +0000 [warn]: #0 [out_os] Could not communicate to OpenSearch, resetting connection and trying again. No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -  (Errno::ENOENT)
```

When running some test pod in the cluster, I can communicate with the domain:

```
$ kubectl run -it --image=ubuntu:22.04 test -- bash
$ curl https://vpc-eks-opensearch-domain-abc.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com
{
  "name" : "ca8942c235ac0f8dc90bebc36023d94a",
  "cluster_name" : "315761808707:eks-opensearch-domain",
  "cluster_uuid" : "QLLYKgUBSEi0PKVEpmG5NA",
  "version" : {
    "distribution" : "opensearch",
    "number" : "2.3.0",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "unknown",
    "build_date" : "2023-03-22T14:16:51.874273Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "9.3.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.10.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "The OpenSearch Project: https://opensearch.org/"
}
```

Not only that, if I run an OpenSearch instance in my EKS cluster, fluentd can communicate with it without any problem.

Can someone help with that? What is this "No such file or directory" ?

Comment: Two questions. Does the fluentd configmap exist in the same namespace as the deployment? Can you enable debug logging to get more details on the error?